# How to modify SaSS variable value before running CSS Gulp task

Tags: css, json, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a list of json files, each containing a few key-value pairs that indicate colors, text size and other such information. I also have a set of `scss` files, including a `variables.scss` file with default values for those very variables (color, text size etc.). 
How can I obtain a Gulp task to generate as many `css` files as there are json files, after replacing the default variables' values with those indicated in the json files?

`JSON` file example:

```
{
    "css": {
        "color": "#337019",
        "textSize": "15px"
    }

}
```

Base `variables.scss` file content:

```
$themeColor: #356AA0;
$fontSize: 13px;
```

In the example above, the value of *color* in the `json` file would substitute the value of the `$themeColor` variable from the `scss` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this Gulp package in your build: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-sass

I used it before to convert this JSON:

```
{
    "black": {
        "base": "#000000"
    },
    "blue": {
        "base": "#0000aa"
    }
}
```

to this SCSS file:

```
$palettes: (
    black: (
        base: #000000
    ),
    blue: (
        base: #0000aa
    )
);
```

with this simple Gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jsonSass = require('json-sass');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var fs = require('fs');

var sourceFolder = 'json/';
var sourceFileName = sourceFolder + 'colors.json';
var destFolder = 'css/scss/partials/';
var destFileName = '_json-colors.scss';

gulp.task('sass-json-colors', function() {
    return fs.createReadStream(sourceFileName)
    .pipe(jsonSass({
        prefix: '$palettes: ',
    }))
    .pipe(source(sourceFileName))
    .pipe(rename(destFileName))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destFolder));
});
```